# Extracting the Domain from the URL using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cgi

I am currently using CGI variables to extract the full URL and the hostname from the current URL:

```
<cfset currentURL = CGI.SERVER_NAME>
<cfset host = ListFirst(currentURL, ".")>
```

The previous code works as expected.

I would like to also extract the domain. I can't find a CGI variable for that surprisingly, and I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
<cfset domain = ListLast(currentURL, "#host#")>
```

But the domain variable is only showing 'om' instead of 'domain.com' when I output it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The 2nd argument should be a delimiter. Though that would still return the wrong value: "com". Also, keep in mind there could be a subdomain or an IP, so... more than one period in the string

Comment: (https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1692-ask-ben-getting-the-domain-name-from-the-referer-url.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it and it will handle domains with multiple subdomain parts (e.g., local.dev.mydomain.com).

```
<cfset currentURL = CGI.SERVER_NAME>

<cfset domainParts = listLen(currentURL, ".")>

<cfset domain = gettoken(currentURL,domainParts-1,".") & "." & gettoken(currentURL,domainParts,".") >
```

Answer (score 1):

The full URL would be:

`'#getPageContext().getRequest().getScheme()#://#cgi.server_name#/#cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#'`

That will include protocol, path, and url variables.

The domain name is simply `#cgi.server_name#`.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - You didn't say how the values will be used, but **don't** use CGI variables to construct a URL like above unless you're absolutely about the variable source. Some web servers utilize client supplied information and using url's built from those values could allow malicious users to exploit vulnerabilities like header injection.